# Center h1 over image in a div

Tags: html, css

How to center (**vertically,horizontally**) properly  over an image in a ?

```
<div class="category-info">
    <div class="image">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="image.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.category-info {
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    width: 770px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The image is 770px width and 200px height. I don't what to do next with . I tried several things, without success.

[image: test image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/QjLuP/4/

The CSS:

```
.image{
    position: relative;
    background: green; /* IE */
}
.image h1{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -13px; /* 1/2 height */
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
    background: rgba(170, 0, 0, 0.8); /* CSS3 */
}
.image img{
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:green
}
```

Comment: One more thing, I want h1 to be centered vertically/horizontally too (to the center of the image).

Comment: I added to your previous code line-height: 200px (h1) and it is works. I think this way is easier? If you accept my solution, please change back the code. :) Thank you

Comment: Hmm, interesting, but why?

Comment: Too much tweaking involved for my taste.  Say you want to change the font size.  You then have to change the height of the h1, then the margin to half the height.

Comment: @tedski But that's only needed once. The inline styles for width and height take care of the implementation specifics.

Comment: Is it possible to write CSS that will center over any arbitrary image - that is of any width or height or do you have to specify the width and height in the style somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I threw a position relative on the `.image` class and set the width and height on the image element (that way it doesn't resize when it loads). I changed the table back to the `h1` and added your line-height of 200px.  That is the only downside, you'll still have to manually set the line-height of the `h1`.

HTML:

```
<div class="category-info">
    <div class="image">
         <h1>Title</h1>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/770/200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.category-info {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image{
    position:relative;
}

.image img{
    width:770px;
    height:200px;
}

.image h1{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    line-height:200px;
    margin:0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wGwL/2/

Comment: Just read the "horizontally/vertically" requirement.. vertical centering is very hard to do... looking into it.

Comment: Why have the table? Slows rendering.

Comment: Idk it was the only reliable way I've seen to get vertically aligned content. and it's 47 characters... not really going to significantly slow the site down.

Comment: tedski, thanks for the update. I use the same code (this was Mooseman's original code), but he says it may not work everywhere. I am little confused.

Comment: Not sure what he's referencing. I don't really see a reason for it to break in other browsers. I just think my solution is cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
h1 { text-align:center; }
```

Comment: I tried. :) The h1 will be on the top of the image, not over it.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<h1 style="background-image:url(your php source.img)">Title</h1>
```

css :

```
h1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 770px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:200px;
    background:transparent no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
   }
```

and nothing else

Comment: unfortunately this not working in my case, because <img> source is coming from the php code/database.

Comment: @Adrian : i modified the code in order to receive your image IN-code.